# How can I implement dynamic rowspan

Tags: javascript, meteor

The code below is my latest attempt. There have been many others:

Javascript:

```
...
    var issueArray = [];
    _.each(issueGroups, function(i) {
      var x = {
        issue: i[0].issue,
        comment: i[0].comment,
        count: i.length,
        new_row: 1
      };
      issueArray.push(x);
    });
    issueArray[0].new_row = 0;

    var x = {
      test: t[0].test,
      issues: issueArray,
      rowspan: issueArray.length
    };
    finalResult.push(x);
});

return finalResult;
```

The important thing to note here is that for each element of `finalResult` there is an array called `issues` that has a member called `new_row` which is true for all but the first row.

Template:

```
...
<tbody>
  {{#each failuresByTest}}
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="{{rowspan}}">{{test}}</td>
      {{#each issues}}
        {{#if new_row}}
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="https://www.bughost.com/browse/{{issue}}">{{issue}}</a></td>
            <td>{{comment}}</td>
            <td>{{count}}</td>
        {{else}}
            <td><a href="https://www.bughost.com/browse/{{issue}}">{{issue}}</a></td>
            <td>{{comment}}</td>
            <td>{{count}}</td>
        {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
...
```

My data is such that the first element of `finalResult` has 3 issues. I expect it to look like this:

```
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Test1</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Bug 1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>Bug 2</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>654</td>
    <td>Bug 4</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
```

But it ends up looking like this:

```
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Test1</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Bug 1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  <td>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>456</td>
          <td>Bug 2</td>
          <td>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>654</td>
          <td>Bug 4</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

However Meteor doesn't like this. I get:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While processing files with templating-compiler (for target web.browser):
   client/templates/runs/run_page.html:128: Unexpected HTML close tag
   </tr>   <tr>     <td><a h...
```

This side-tracked me so badly that I ended up putting the row tags wrongly to fix this and then it displayed wrongly. I have now edited the question accordingly since this is my real problem.

How do I solve this and persuade Meteor that actually I do know better than it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around Meteor's controlling behaviour with the following.

Javascript:

```
    var issueArray = [];
    _.each(issueGroups, function(i) {
      var x = {
        issue: i[0].issue,
        comment: i[0].comment,
        count: i.length,
        new_row: 0
      };
      issueArray.push(x);
    });
    issueArray[0].new_row = 1;
    _.extend(issueArray[0], {rowspan: issueArray.length});
    _.extend(issueArray[0], {test: t[0].test});

    var x = {
      issues: issueArray
    };
    finalResult.push(x);
```

Note that the test name and rowspan have now moved into the first array element. I can probably remove `new_row`.

Template:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each failuresByTest}}
    {{#each issues}}
      <tr>
        {{#if new_row}}
          <td rowspan="{{rowspan}}">{{test}}</td>
        {{/if}}
        <td><a href="https://www.bughost.com/browse/{{issue}}">{{issue}}</a></td>
        <td>{{comment}}</td>
        <td>{{count}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I really do not like putting "parent data" in the first array element. I prefer for all elements to be of exactly the same type/structure without duplicate/extra information added.

Answer (score 2):

Your template logic is flawed:
You are trying to insert a new `<tr>` inside a `<td>`. Since `<tr>` can only be contained inside tables, the browser will automatically add a table around it so that the html is valid.

```
<tbody>
  {{#each failuresByTest}}
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="{{rowspan}}">{{test}}</td>
      {{#each issues}}
        {{#if new_row}}
          <tr>
            <td>
```

So depending on how each failureBytest should be rendered, you should either create a new table for each failure, or create a new row outside the previous row inseatd of inside it's cells.

Comment: I got my <tr> and </tr> the wrong way around. I think I had it right at one point, but then got it wrong. One problem I had is that when I put it the right way around, Meteor complains about mis-matched HTML tags. That ended up forcing me into this wrong path.

Comment: I think I'll edit the question to reflect the real problem I had that forced me here.